# Receiving an error in typescript using emotion/styled when trying to add a custom property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

This is the line of code I'm trying to implement.

```
const MaybeBigHeading = styled(Heading)( ({ big:boolean = false }) => [ big && tw`text-4xl` ]);
```

The error I receive is:

```
Property 'big' does not exist on type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> & { theme?: Theme | undefined; } & { ...; }'.ts(2339)
```

The error kind of makes sense to me, but I'm learning ReactJS/Typescript and am trying to implement something from a Javascript tutorial; this works in Javascript, but not in Typescript.

Not sure how to get around this in Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for the `styled` function is something called a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). A generic allows you to pass in your own types via parameters. Generic parameters are put between the angled brackets (`<>`). In your case, you'd use it like this:

```js
const MaybeBigHeading = styled(Heading)<{ big?: boolean; }>(({ big = false }) => [ big && tw`text-4xl text-red-300` ]);
```

See documentation on using [TypeScript with Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript) too. You can see how the generic type for `styled` is defined [here](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/4be3391914878fd41279701bc23332b75903ec43/packages/styled/types/base.d.ts#L118).

#### A note on the solution you've discovered

In the solution you've discovered, you've extended the `HTMLAttributes` interface by adding your own type for `big`:

```
declare module "react" {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    big?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Yes, this works but it's essentially a brute force method for when no other options exist. It's not a good idea because it's polluting the meaning of what an HTML attribute is and will likely cause confusion to future readers of your code (potentially yourself). `big` is not an HTML attribute so should not existing on the HTML attributes interface.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution shortly after posting this

By adding

```
declare module "react" {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    big?: boolean;
  }
}
```

to the .tsx file, I was able to use "big" as an attribute for a new Component

Full App.tsx file follows

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react  */
import tw from "twin.macro";
import { DOMAttributes } from "react";

import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Heading= tw.h1`text-blue-500 text-2xl p-2`;
const BigHeading = tw(Heading)`text-4xl`;
declare module "react" {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
    big?: boolean;
  }
}
const MaybeBigHeading = styled(Heading)( ({ big = false }) => [ big && tw`text-4xl text-red-300` ]);
const Container = tw.div`max-w-4xl mx-auto p-5 mt-5`;
function App() {
  return (
    <Container >
      <BigHeading>Hello World</BigHeading>
      <Heading>This is an example</Heading>
      <MaybeBigHeading>This might be a Big Heading</MaybeBigHeading>
      <MaybeBigHeading big>This IS a Big Heading</MaybeBigHeading>
      
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```